# Help Creating a Style for a ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, formatting, listboxitem

I am new to styles and need help to create a style for a ListBoxItem that will give the item a transparent background then have the Font turn Gold when hovered over.  It should not change the color when clicked and return to normal when the mouse moves off.  It must still pass the selected object to the PreviewMouseRightButtonDown event for the ListBox

I currently use a default dictionary from REUXABLES THEMES, but it is way to much coloring for this portion of the display on the application.

Thanks,

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemsTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
              Margin="0,5,0,5"
              Width="{Binding 
              Path=ActualWidth,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
              Mode=FindAncestor, 
              AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}" MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
              AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ViewportWidth}" >
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=CID}" />
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0" >
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Label Foreground="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" >Posted by</Label>
                        <Label Foreground="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding Path=ACID}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>
                         <Label Foreground="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" Margin="3,0,0,0">at</Label>
                        <Label Foreground="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" Margin="3,0,3,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding Path=Type}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Label Foreground="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}">(</Label>
                        <Label Foreground="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding Path=Route}" />
                        <Label Foreground="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}">)</Label>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="ItemsListBox" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Transparent}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Transparent}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Transparent}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    </Style>

<ListBox x:Name="ListViewFlightPlans" Grid.Column="0" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemsTemplate}" 
                         MaxWidth="800" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,0,1">

            </ListBox>
```

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately changing `BorderBrush` for the `ListBoxItem` won't have your desired effect, since the `Border` with the selection highlight is internal to the `ControlTemplate` of the `ListBoxItem`.

Instead, you can add a new `Brush` resource with the key of [SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.highlightbrushkey.aspx), this is the key that the `ListBoxItem` uses for setting the selection highlight color.

The inactive selection brush uses the key of [SystemColors.ControlBrushKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.controlbrushkey.aspx), so if you override both of these with a transparent `Brush` you're guaranteed not to have any selection color.  You can read more about it in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/08/31/specifying-the-selection-color-content-alignment-and-background-color-for-items-in-a-listbox.aspx).

Here's an example with everything but your `DataTemplate`:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="data" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>a </sys:String>
            <sys:String>bb</sys:String>
            <sys:String>ccc</sys:String>
            <sys:String>dddd</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource data}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```